# Measuring Performance of Class Instantiation with JMH

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

I'm new to writing benchmarks and would like some advice whether I am doing this correctly.

I currently have two classes: `Person.java` and `PersonFinaliser.java` which each have a single field `age`. The only difference is that `PersonFinaliser.java` has a `finalizer()` method.

I am trying to measure the perfomance difference between creating objects from classes with and without `finalize()` overidden. I know it has been deprecated since Java 9, but I am testing a number of optimisation techniques as part of my dissertation.

```java
public class Person {

    private int age;

    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

```java
public class PersonFinaliser {

    private int age;

    public PersonFinaliser(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        age++;
    }
}
```

```java
@Fork(warmups = 5, value = 5)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, batchSize = 5000)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, batchSize = 5000)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class FinaliserBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BenchmarkState {
        int age = 18;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Person personBenchmark(BenchmarkState state) {
        return new Person(state.age);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public PersonFinaliser personFinaliserBenchmark(BenchmarkState state) {
        return new PersonFinaliser(state.age);
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting seems to be what I expect, with low error margins.

```
Benchmark                                    Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
FinaliserBenchmark.personBenchmark             ss   50  0.210 ± 0.060  ms/op
FinaliserBenchmark.personFinaliserBenchmark    ss   50  0.852 ± 0.074  ms/op
```

Have I done this correctly or is there a better way to perform this benchmark? Thanks!

Comment: According to https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/99e9c19c80a0133c28f6532ef2b5776d5b8bd023/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Mode.java#L65  `Mode.SingleShotTime` estimates the "cold" performance. For you to decide if this is something you want to account for.